# UUID field not being updated on user creation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to assign a UUID which is just a random generated string to a user on registration. I have added it to my database as a simple `$table->string('uuid')->nullable();` and within `RegisterController.php` I'm attempting to add it on sign up like so:

```
return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    'uuid' => rand(1, 13000)
]);
```

The issue I'm having is that the column of `uuid` is always just null, it never gets added.

I have confirmed that the field is being added to my DB, it just doesn't get updated on user creation.

Comment: then the problem isn't on that code block you just posted but the way you're presenting it, and shouldn't be uuid's are `AA97B177-9383-4934-8543-0F91A7A02836` like so? why is there are `rand` in there

Comment: @Kevin I'm checking direct on the DB and it is not being added. I'm just calling it a UUID, I really mean just a unique string.

Comment: Can you show us the model declaration that includes UUID as a property?

Comment: @beltouche On my User.php file I have it added to the `$fillable` array.

Comment: add `DB::getQueryLogs()` to debug the raw sql.

Comment: Try `composer dumpautoload`, and do refresh your migrations.

Answer (score 1):

`rand` function should not be used to generate uuid.

Instead in **laravel 5.6+** there is a helper to generate Universal Unique Identifiers (UUID).

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return (string) Str::uuid();
```

[Laravel API ->  Str -> uuid](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Support/Str.html#method_uuid)

Comment: The problem I'm having isn't generating the string... it's adding it to the column on the db.

Comment: @JoeScotto I know the the problem isn't generating the string but this to enlighten other that one should not use `rand` to generate `uuid`

Comment: This this might have been more appropriate as a comment rather than an answer. Nonetheless, I for one did find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to add `'uuid'` to the `$fillable` property on your user model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'uuid',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you need to restart the process that's serving your PHP? Not sure how you are testing it out. I tried my solution using `php artisan tinker` and had to remember to restart the tinker session to make it pick up the changes to the model.

Comment: I restarted Valet and still have the same issue. I should mention that I'm on Laravel 7.